# Make JQuery UI tabs look like buttons

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like to have a tab-like interface like the one in this page:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

Except that I would like the tabs to look more like buttons like:

http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Where the group of tabs would look like the group of radio buttons above. Is there a way I can change the way the tabs look so they look more like the "radio" buttons on the second link? Or is there another approach you'd recommend to make the tabs look like buttons? Thanks!

Comment: Where each "tab" would basically be a button. ? You want to replace jQuery-ui fonctionnality (using ul > li ) to use <buttons> ?

Comment: Sorry I meant that each tab would look like a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your wished html + css.classes

```
<div id="radio" class="ui-buttonset">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="radio1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 1</span></label>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" id="radio2" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="radio2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 2</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="radio3" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 3</span></label>
</div>
```

and here is a jQuery-ui TAB

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, you want to display TABS has the ui-buttonset .. just re-use the classes by redesigning your html.

```
<ul class="ui-buttonset">
    <li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><a href="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-text">
```

but this might be a harsh one to just 'recycle' jQuery-ui classes.

I suggest you to rewrite your own .css to overwrite with the styling associated. I mean, rewrite jQuery-ui TABS styling instead of attempting to recycle .css classes.

Comment: I'm not understand what you mean. How would I overwrite my CSS to change the styling of the tabs?

Comment: Oh, then you should modify your question for something more realistic. Your problem is that you don't know much about css & html, not that you have a specific buggy context of some sort.